# python3.6.x and opencv using Ubuntu 18.04: import cv2 not found

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04

Using `Python 3.6.7` and `opencv` (I have tried many versions using git checkout and the tags for corresponding versions).

I get the error message

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'". I am using Ubuntu 18.04 for my OS.

Is there a recommended version of `opencv` to use with `Python 3.6.7`?

Comment: This solution resolved my issues: conda install -c conda-forge opencv

conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conda install -c conda-forge opencv

conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv

source:[Opencv](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) Installation